# Segmentation error that occurs when there is no initialized variable defined

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am working with pointers in C. I encountered a problem while dealing with the pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int x = 1, y = 2, z[10];
  int *ip;  
  
  printf("initial value of x:%d\n",x);
  printf("initial value of y:%d\n",y);
  printf("inital value of ip: %d\n",*ip);
    
  return 0;
}
```

This program works properly. But in the program below,Segmentation fault occurs when there is no initialized variable defined.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int x = 1, y = 2;
  int *ip;  
  
  printf("initial value of x:%d\n",x);
  printf("initial value of y:%d\n",y);
  printf("inital value of ip: %d\n",*ip);
    
  return 0;
}
```

Why does this error occur? What is the relationship between segmentation error and variable definition?

Comment: There's no relationship. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer causes undefined behavior. Sometimes that produces a segmentation fault, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Dereferencing the uninitialized pointer `ip` causes undefined behavior.  A segmentation error is just one of the many bad things that could happen.  Appearing to work is another.

Comment: It's important to understand that the first program does not "work properly". It doesn't fail with a segfault on your computer with your compiler settings, but that's not the same as saying that it works properly.

Comment: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) and [nasal demons: n.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this error occur?

Both programs contain undefined behavior, so the expectation is that both of them do not work.

The issue is that you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer:

```
int *ip; // uninitialized, may contain any value

// ...

printf("...", *ip);
           // ^^^ dereference
```

That dereference may give you apparently random data, a constant value or give a segmentation fault.

What exactly happens depends on your compiler, your architecture, your operating system, the optimization flags and other details.

> What is the relationship between segmentation error and variable definition?

There is no relationship. The definition of `z` here is making your first program "seem to work" by chance. As soon as you change something else (like updating your compiler to a new version), it may stop "working" again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm using gcc. Still, the work of the program with the definition of the z[10] variable seems fascinating to me :)

Comment: @Red20 You're welcome! Trying to reason about what a modern compiler does is kind of magical until you have enough experience with both the language specification and optimization passes, so do not worry about it. There are way more surprising things out there that you will see when dealing with UB :-)